"Favorite bodhran technique" deleted as "spam, rude, or abusive"?
I'm surprised this question was deleted by @elementsinspace. The original text was:

What's your favorite technique for achieving a rich, resonant tone on the bodhran Irish drum?

The words "Irish drum" were linked to a url at lapostexaminer.com , with "selecting-your-first-drum" as part of the url, but the site shows a 404 page and can't find the article.
The question was posted by a user who had never had any other activity, had 1 reputation, and had been open for 7 months. It attracted 4 downvotes, one close vote, and only one explanatory comment ("Welcome, but sorry, this site isn't a discussion site for opinions, as you'll see when you read the Help Centre. Hence all the dvs.").
I'm curious; was there reason to suspect the user of bad intent that isn't clear to me? Because I was all set to chide the downvoters and vtc-ers for being so reactive to a single word. Replace "your favorite" with "an effective" and it seems like a reasonable question about technique. (Perhaps a problematic one because there ain't but so many variables with a simple frame drum—the answer probably involves selection of tipper, where you hit it, and probably more than anything how you mic it if recording.) And admittedly the question could be improved by telling more about what they're currently trying and what they don't like about it.
But it's not "rude or abusive," and the dead link didn't seem to be spam. I would have thought this question should be encouraged to improve rather than closed.

The user who posted that question actually has had other activity on our site — you just can’t see it.  (In fact, I instantly recognised that particular user name.)
In November, they posted five posts (1 question and 4 answers).  All were about the Bodhrán, but they were of very low quality, accrued lots of NaN flags, and didn’t really attempt to ask a real question or provide a real answer.  And some of their posts contained spam links to a website selling Bodhráns.
Moderators and reviewers (including yourself in one case) left comments directing them to improve their posts, or simply asking them not to add spam links.  The user didn’t respond to any of these comments, and so their posts ended up getting deleted — that’s why you can’t see them.
That recent question was correctly flagged as spam, which is why I promptly deleted it.
